# How to convert list of json objects to pojo list of strings that contains some field from each object?

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have a JSON document that describe list of objects, it looks something like this:

```
[
   {
     "txId": "ffff",
     "sender" : "0xwwwwwww",
     "recepient" : "0xeferfef"
   },
   {
     "txId": "ffff",
     "sender" : "0xwwwwwww",
     "recepient" : "0xeferfef"
   }
   ...

   ...
]
```

How can I get `List<String>` that contains `txId` values from each object using only Jackson API (without converting this JSON to a list of pojo-objects then proceed this list by foreach and create new list of strings)?

Comment: Why don't you want to convert them into java objects? Without parsing you would need to handle stuff like `parser.nextToken() != JsonToken.END_OBJECT` and so on. With pojo all you need is to parse and then use java streams to convert list of objects to list of strings.

Comment: Which version of jackson are you using?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can always read a JSON document as `JsonNode` object with Jackson API (no need of creating POJO). Next, there are several ways of reading and manipulating the data represented as `JsonNode` object. One of the most convenient ways available from Java 8+ is to create a `java.util.Stream<JsonNode>` and collect the final list as a result of a mapping from `JsonNode` to `String`, where `String` is represents a value of `node.txId` field.

You can [create `java.util.Stream<JsonNode>` with](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/StreamSupport.html#stream-java.util.Spliterator-boolean-):

```
java.util.stream.StreamSupport.stream(jsonNode.spliterator(), false)
```

and then you can call `map(node -> node.get("txId").textValue()` and finally call `collect()` to terminate the stream and get your expected result.

Consider following code as an example (requires Java 8+):

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.StreamSupport;

final class JacksonReadExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        final String json = " [\n" +
                "   {\n" +
                "     \"txId\": \"ffff-001\",\n" +
                "     \"sender\" : \"0xwwwwwww\",\n" +
                "     \"recepient\" : \"0xeferfef\"\n" +
                "   },\n" +
                "   {\n" +
                "     \"txId\": \"ffff-002\",\n" +
                "     \"sender\" : \"0xwwwwwww\",\n" +
                "     \"recepient\" : \"0xeferfef\"\n" +
                "   }\n" +
                "]";

        final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

        final JsonNode jsonNode = mapper.readTree(json);

        final List<String> ids = StreamSupport.stream(jsonNode.spliterator(), false)
                .map(node -> node.get("txId").textValue())
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

        System.out.println(ids);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
[ffff-001, ffff-002]
```

Comment: Thank you! Your answer is very helpful.